# Same texture to multiple faces

Tags: texturing, uv

I created two planes.
[image: My planes]
Plane 1 (left): I applied image texture, then unwrap, then I loop cut etc. No prob.

Plane 2 (right): I started by modifying the shape (loop cut) and then I applied texture.

How can I have the same render than Plane 1?

My settings.

[image: My settings]

Edit: After UV unwrap and removed doubles:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you UV Unwrapped it?

Comment: yes, I have a weird texture

Comment: It looks like you may have some "Z Fighting" (Overlapping faces). Try removing doubles etc...

Comment: It's getting closer but still have an issue...

Comment: Ok, can upload you .blend file into your original question using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Done, but I cannot include textures

Comment: Some of your normals are inverted. In edit mode, select all, Ctrl+N, then redo your unwrap